# Set orthographic view using python?

Tags: python, 3d-view, orthographic

Is there a python function that sets ortho view such that X and Y axes are visible - the equivalent of numpad 7?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Enable python tooltips in the preferences, then go to *View > Viewpoint > Top* and wait a second.

Comment: Thanks; when I tried the code it threw this error:  RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: Common question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: Why wouldn't this work:      for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type=='VIEW_3D':
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) when calling [view_axis()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=view_axis#bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis) operator.

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        with context.temp_override(area=area, region=area.regions[-1]):
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP')
        break
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(override, type='TOP')
        break
```