# How to set view to XY-plane in python script?

Tags: python, 3d-view

I want to set the view to the XY-plane by using python script, so I have this as a result:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(override, type='TOP')
        break
```

Found here: [Set orthographic view using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149835/set-orthographic-view-using-python)